# Безопасное копирование файлов при блокировке процессом

Tags: c#

Суть вопроса:
Запущен процесс программы, мне нужно от программы скопировать файлы и сохранить в памяти.
Для сохранения использую `MemoryStream`.
Так вот он не даёт скопировать в себя файл(ы) если открыт процесс программы из которой я копирую файлы.

Вот почему если открыт процесс, то я могу сделать это через `File.Copy` (но с записью на диск) в отдельной папке.
А вот в память не могу скопировать(
Такое вообще возможно сделать?

Comment: Код, который дает ошибку, вы конечно же не покажете?

Comment: @aepot, ошибка: Файл *.log занят другим процессом.  Собственно это и есть вся причина.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли мой комментарий. Я разве спрашивал текст ошибки?

Comment: Используйте FileStream с mode - Open, acces - Read

Comment: @Yotic Можно проще `using var fs = File.OpenRead(path);` и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете скопировать безопасно файл(ы) в памяти, это реализовывается очень просто.
Создаёте память для записи:

```
using System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new() { Position = 0};
```

Затем читаете нужны(е)й Вам файл(ы) и записываете в `MemoryStream`

```
 using System.IO.FileStream fs = new(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
 fs.CopyTo(ms);
 fs?.Close();  // Если поток не закрылся (закрываем принудительно!)
```

Затем просто возвращаем `MemoryStream` и на выходе будут наши файлы:

```
ms?.ToArray() ?? ms.GetBuffer() ?? System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)
```

Comment: `Position = 0` лишнее, это значение по умолчанию. `fs?.Close();` лишнее, `using` гарантированно закроет файл, он для того и нужен. Последняя строчка вообще не понял, `ms` не может быть `null`, `ms.ToArray()` не может вернуть `null`, а значит всё что дальше - мусор. Да и автор хотел просто `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileToCopyPath = "C:\\log.txt";
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(fileToCopyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    sr.CopyTo(memory);
```